# When i use a image texture with transparent background it makes the image dissapear and the transparent part stays

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image

So when i go in cycles render and set up the nodes for making the transparent part dissapear, but when i connect the alpha to the mix shader (Factor) with the transparent shader it makes the actual image transparent and the transparent part stays black.
The image i use: http://www.textures.com/download/leaves0118/27464?q=Leaves 
i used image 2.

Any suggestions???
Can figure it out, seen tutorials on how to and make is exact the same and still no luck

Blender 2.78

Comment: Most times this happens because the order is wrong as far as the mix shader goes. The top socket is the base, and the bottom socket is the next/upper level, so try inverting the order the components are fed into these and see if the effect reverses course.

Comment: OMG just had to change the connections of the mix shader..... soooo dumb, ty for the help

Answer (score 2):

The connections on the mix shader are wrong...
Transparent must be on the first shader and the actual image on the second then the alpha on the factor